# How can I keep my TAG extension from being called every time I log something?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I just realized my `TAG` extension code is getting called every time I log something. It makes sense that it is called every time but I'm wondering how can I stop that from happening every time?

This is my `TAG` code:

```
val Any.TAG: String
    get() {
        return if (!javaClass.isAnonymousClass) {
            val name = javaClass.simpleName
            if (name.length <= 23 || OSUtils.nougatMR1OrHigher) name else name.substring(0, 23)// first 23 chars
        } else {
            val name = javaClass.name
            if (name.length <= 23 || OSUtils.nougatMR1OrHigher) name else name.substring(name.length - 23, name.length)// last 23 chars
        }
    }
```

And it gets used like `Log.i(TAG,"some lod")`

One simple solution would be to make a class variable in every class that holds the value but if I do that then it kind of misses the point of the extension.

Comment: it's not really possible to add properties to an existing class without reflection

Comment: If you’re using this function for tagging log messages, does it really matter? You shouldn’t be logging in production code anyway. You might consider using the Timber library so the tag is only generated when logging, and logging only occurs when in a debug build.

Comment: Because of the nature of devices my app interacts with, I need to be able to get user logs pretty often. So certain log lines are still on production. So of them are on loops though that is rare.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is simple memoization by caching the computation result, this won't stop this being treated like a function call, but will mean the computation is only performed once.

Something like :

```
private val bagOfTags : MutableMap<Class<Any>, String> = ConcurrentHashMap()


val Any.TAG: String
    get() {
        return bagOfTags.computeIfAbsent(javaClass) {
            if (!javaClass.isAnonymousClass) {
                val name = javaClass.simpleName
                if (name.length <= 23 || OSUtils.nougatMR1OrHigher) name else name.substring(0, 23)// first 23 chars
            } else {
                val name = javaClass.name
                if (name.length <= 23 || OSUtils.nougatMR1OrHigher) name else name.substring(name.length - 23, name.length)// last 23 chars
            }
        }
    }
```